# How to assign validation group through Java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Not able to assign validation group on the click of button.

```
<asp:TabPanel ID="tabpnlTwo" runat="server" Visible="false" Width="100%" OnClientClick="radiobuttonvalidationForTabOne">
       <ContentTemplate>
  </ContentTemplate>

<asp:TabPanel ID="tabpnlTwo" runat="server" Visible="false" Width="100%" OnClientClick="radiobuttonvalidationForTabTwo">
       <ContentTemplate>
  </ContentTemplate>
```

here on the tabpnanel calling script function onClientClick where assigning validation group to button

```
  <script>
    function radiobuttonvalidationForTabOne() {
        var btnAddOrderId = document.getElementById("btnAddToOrder");
        btnAddOrderId.ValidationGroup = "tabpnlOneGroup";

        alert(btnAddOrderId.ValidationGroup);
    }
    </script>

    <script>
function radiobuttonvalidationForTabTwo() {
    var btnAddOrderId = document.getElementById("btnAddToOrder");
    btnAddOrderId.ValidationGroup = "tabpnlTwoGroup";
    alert(btnAddOrderId.ValidationGroup);
}
</script>


 <asp:Button ID="btnAddToOrder" CssClass="customButton" runat="server" Text="Add To Order" ValidationGroup="tabpnlOneGroup"
           onclick="btnAddToOrder_Click" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
<anycontrol runat="server" id="anyone" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
```

Using ClientIDMode Static with the control's attribute will solve your problem.

No Using Jquery or javascript:

```
$('#anyone').anyfunctioncallback()
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the id of you button changes on run time. You need to use

```
 var btnAddOrderId = document.getElementById('<%=btnAddToOrder.ClientID%>');
```

instead of

```
 var btnAddOrderId = document.getElementById("btnAddToOrder");
```